# jest testing with babel undefined (reading 'getCacheKey')

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

FAIL  tests/Unit/example.spec.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getCacheKey')

  at Object.getCacheKey (node_modules/vue3-jest/lib/index.js:13:19)
```

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.544s
Ran all test suites.

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.8.4",
    "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.3.5",
    "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.4",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.15",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-jest": "^22.4.3",
    "flush-promises": "^1.0.2",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-loader": "^16.1.2",
    "vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.1"
  }
```

jest.config.js

```
const config = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest',
  collectCoverage: true,
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue3-jest',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  testMatch:["**/tests/Unit/*.spec.[jt]s?(x)"],

  verbose: true,
};
```

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue, for me updating `babel-jest` to the latest version (27.5.1) fixed the issue.